# How to determine if file system path is directory or file?

Tags: node.js, file, directory, filesystems, file-type

I'm looking to determine if a file system path is directory or file. I'm not looking to checking for the type an existing path. I'm trying to determine if the path function argument string is a referring to a directory or file.

How do I make a distinction between a file and a directory when this:

```
/Users/thomas/Desktop/node
```

The following path could refer to a directory `node`, or a file `node` without an extension.

I was thinking about using a trailing `/` to connote directory.

So this would mean a directory:

```
/Users/thomas/Desktop/node/
```

And this would mean a file:

```
/Users/thomas/Desktop/node
```

However node's `path` methods like `.resolve()` and `.join()` do not take into consideration the trailing `/` and always remove it. So is this good practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to check if an arbitrary string is a directory or file if it does not exist.

However for existing paths, you can use [`fs.stat()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback) on the path, which will give you an object that has methods for checking the path type (e.g. `isDirectory()`, `isFile()`, etc).